# how to use call inside filter in redux-saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

I'm new to generator function. I'm trying to use filter similar to map function but its not working

```
const ytids = yield all(
  possibleYtids.filter((ytid) => {
    return call(extraVideoEligiblity, ytid);
  })
);
```

i'm calling a different generator function inside the filter. it doesnt call `extraVideoEligiblity` function just return same array as before

Comment: Paste the `call` function. Also what is `all()`?

Comment: @curious_coder rather than calling, pasting the code inside the filter ?

Comment: I don't see any generator function in your code.

Comment: @curious_coder its related to redux-saga https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/1090

Comment: Are there any errors? Is `const ytids` inside a function?

Comment: Currently nothing yields the call effect. Do you want `ytids` to contain only ids that `extraVideoEligiblity` returns true for?

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` instead of `filter`.

```
const ytids = yield all(
  possibleYtids.map((ytid) => {
    return call(extraVideoEligiblity, ytid);
  })
);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

The result of `filter` is the original elements of the array for which the test function returns a truthy value, so in the original implementation all of the elements of the original array are being passed to `yield all` instead of the `call` effects.